# VLC as RTSP Server (Windows) - Authentication not working

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, authentication, rtsp

I know there is another thread with a similar question, but was recommended create a new one.

With VLC, I am opening a file or a RTSP stream from a camera and restream it with VLC RTSP. I tried a lot of combinations and never ask for credentials. I don't get any error.

The code I tried:

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=Auto,acodec=none,scodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/test}
--sout-rtsp-user=username --sout-rtsp-pwd=password :no-sout-all :sout-keep
```

Already tried with double "-", with ":", change the parameters order... I can play the stream from VLC in other device but never ask for credentials

VLC is updated, the version is 3.0.20
Thanks in advance

Comment: try removing the equals signs and format like `--sout-rtsp-user username --sout-rtsp-pwd password`

Comment: try rtsp://username:password@:8554/test

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Narzard, but dind't work

Comment: @Petepf, I can see the stream without put any credentials. It is indifferent if I put credentials or not if VLC doesn't check them.